# Multiple images one by one JPanel

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

I am trying to load images to JPanel from a directory (which contains only images) one by one. I want to crop the image one by one using mouse events. I wrote program for loading one image by giving it's path to JPanael and then cropping it using mouse. But i don't know how to extend program for multiple images one by one and saving the cropped ones in a different directory. I tried swing timer also but i could not figure how to use it. Can any please help me?

Here is my code for single image.

```
public class MainActivity extends JFrame implements MouseListener,MouseMotionListener{


    int drag_status=0,c1,c2,c3,c4;
    static String[] pathArray = new String[1000];
public static void main(String args[]) {
    new MainActivity().start();

    String s = "G:\\my pic";
    File f = new File(s);
    String str;
    System.out.println(true);

    //just to put all the pictures in list
    File[] fa = f.listFiles();

    for (int i=0; i< fa.length; i++) {
        String path = fa[i].toString();

        str = path.replace("\\", "\\\\");
        pathArray [i] = str;
        System.out.println(pathArray[2]); //gives all the paths in ImagePanel path format 
    }

}


public void start() {

    ImageJPanel imageJPanel=new ImageJPanel(pathArray[1]); 
    add(imageJPanel); 
    setSize(200,200);
    setVisible(true);
    addMouseListener(this); 
    addMouseMotionListener( this ); 
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    }



@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    repaint();
    c1=arg0.getX();
    c2=arg0.getY();
}


@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        repaint(); 
    if(drag_status==1) { 
        c3=arg0.getX(); 
        c4=arg0.getY(); 
        try { 
            draggedScreen(); 
            } 
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }


}

public void draggedScreen()throws Exception { 
    int width = c1 - c3; 
    int height = c2 - c4; 
    width = width * -1; 
    height = height * -1; 
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(c1, c2,width,height));
    File save_path=new File("C:\\Users\\apurvgandhwani\\Desktop\\cropped");
    ImageIO.write(img, "JPG", save_path);
    System.out.println("Saved to folder"); 
    }


@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    repaint();
    drag_status=1;
    c3=arg0.getX();
    c4=arg0.getY();

}
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    int width = c1 - c3; 
    int height = c2 - c4;
    width = width * -1; 
    height = height * -1; 

    if(width<0) width = width * -1;
    g.drawRect(c1, c2, width, height);  }

}
```

And ImageJPanel class

```
public class ImageJPanel extends JPanel{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private Image image;
int x = 0;  
public ImageJPanel(String image){
    this(new ImageIcon(image).getImage());
    Timer timer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            x += 110;
            if (x >= 1000) {
                x = 1000;
                ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
            }
            repaint();
        }
    });
    timer.start();

}

public ImageJPanel(Image image){
    this.image = image;

    Dimension size = new Dimension(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null)); 
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setMinimumSize(size); 
    setMaximumSize(size); 
    setSize(size); 
    setLayout(null);
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}

}
```

Comment: Make sure you call `super.paintComponent`, you're going to run into issues other wise.  Expand the functionality of your `ImageJPanel` so it includes a `setImage` and `getImage` method, this way you can use a single instance of the panel, but allow it to manage multiple images.  You will need some kind of navigation mechanism to allow the user to move between images, a simple array or `List` of the files is a good start

Comment: Do i need to use swing timer? It will be great if you could make the required changes to the program. I am really new to this. Thanks in advance

Comment: And get image method is already there in the constructor of ImageJPanel class

Comment: No, you need to methods, one which sets the image and which can get the image, so what ever class is interacting with your panel can update it and know what's working with

Comment: I tried it. But i am not doing it correctly i guess. Can u please make the edits in the code. I tried everything i could.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Can u please help me out